# Need to return JSON with keys through Magento 2 webapi, but M2 removes first-level keys

Tags: json, rest, magento2

I want to return JSON from M2 via webapi

But M2 removes first-level keys

Why is it happens? Is it feature or bug? Can it be ignored?

Magento 2.3.2

In webapi.xml

```xml
    <route url="/V1/testapi" method="GET">
        <service class="Vendor\Module\TestApi" method="fetch"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

Class TestApi

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class TestApi
{ 
   /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function fetch() {
        return [
            'level1_key1' => [
                'level2_key1' => 'testvalue',
            ],
            123 => 'test',
            'level1_key2' => 2,
        ];
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "123": "test",
    "level1_key1": {
        "level2_key1": "testvalue"
    },
    "level1_key2": 2
}
```

Actual result:

```
[
    {
        "level2_key1": "testvalue"
    },
    "test",
    2
]
```

Comment: see this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319266/93504 this one works for me

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177350/magento-2-how-to-return-a-json-object-from-the-api), I think the answers given there will apply to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still cherching solution for that, to have json with associative key you have to return array of your associative array :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class TestApi
{ 
   /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function fetch() {
        $result = [
            'level1_key1' => [
                'level2_key1' => 'testvalue',
            ],
            123 => 'test',
            'level1_key2' => 2,
        ];
        return [$result];
    }
}
```

Then you will get something like that :

```
[
    {
        "level1_key1": {
            "level2_key1": "testvalue"
        },
        "123": "test",
        "level1_key2": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: umm.. no ) Because it changes the data structure (being deeper for 1 level).
Of course its useful trick, but still not the correct solution.
Unfortunately, there's no solution 'from the box'. U have to change data structure (as shown in this answer, for example) or modify Magento core